# Ruby on rails implode and explode functions to change date format

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date

How do we explode a string on '-' and again implode it on '-' in ruby on rails.My problem is that i want to convert a date in `"MM-DD-YYYY"` format to `'YYYY-MM-DD'` coming  from a form and save it to mysql database.As MySQL will only accept `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails do not support MM-DD-YYYY out of the box. It's often impossible to differ them from DD-MM-YYYY and that could be why.

You can use [Date::strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime)

```
dateMMDDYYY = "10-30-2012"
date = Date.strptime(dateMMDDYYY, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

You do not actually have to format it as YYYY-MM-DD because ActiveRecord just needs a date object.

Comment: Thanks this one worked for me.I was looking for this for a long time :).

Answer (score 3):

if it's coming in as: `"MM-DD-YYYY"`

then i'd to this:

```
m, d, y = "MM-DD-YYYY".split('-')
new_format = [y,m,d].join('-')
```

i've left it in a slightly longer format so that you have more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i decided to use 'Date.strptime(dateMMDDYYY, '%m-%d-%Y')' as it is short and redable.

Comment: While the question was around date-specific context, this answer was more helpful since it actually answered the question of "how to explode/implode a string".

Answer (score 2):

Check [`strftime`](http://www.wetware.co.nz/2009/07/rails-date-formats-strftime/)

```
"31-12-2012".to_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") #Gives "2012-12-31"
```

If you have date time object do following

```
t = Time.now
puts t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: For Record `Time.now.to_s(:db)` Gives date time like `"2012-10-30 17:48:59"`

Comment: My format is "12-31-2012" it not "31-12-2012" and in doing the way you asked,it is giving me 'invalid date' error.

Comment: @SachinPrasad :- `DateTime.strptime("12-31-2012", '%m-%d-%Y')` will give you Mon, `31 Dec 2012 00:00:00 +0000`. So your answer will be `DateTime.strptime("12-31-2012", '%m-%d-%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: You also have to careful using `strptime` it will throw `ArgumentError: invalid date` if date is invalid. for ex:- `DateTime.strptime("13-31-2012", '%m-%d-%Y')`